# Long distance OSM routing, how to work with all that data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, openstreetmap

I am trying to build my own routing system which utilizes OSMSharp, and will eventually have a full website front end deployed to Azure. However, I think I have a serious problem if I want to find a route over a long distance (e.g. NY -> CA). It looks like the routers in OSMSharp just accept a Stream of osm data, however even the binary format (.osm.pbf) will be [roughly 10gb of data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format). Which seems like a huge performance concern.

Either, I need to hold that huge file in memory, and who knows how much Azure is going to charge me for that, or how well OSMSharp/the CLR is going to handle it; or it needs to be broken up and stored in a DB for on-the-fly loading.

Can anyone give any insight into how this is usually handled? Am I way out of my league for a personal project? Maybe I should support just one US State?

Comment: I cannot speak for osmsharp but graphhopper allows you to import a pbf relative memory efficient and fast, always with the possibility to use memory mapped configuration for further reduction of the used RAM (but the import will be slower). The same applies for the queries: GraphHopper can utilize lots of RAM for fast queries or just configure it to use memory mapping with much lower RAM usage. Another way is to use a hosted (OSM) routing service ... hint hint ;)

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but I want to run my own custom routing algorithm. I think that entirely precludes a hosted service. I will look into graphhopper though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Directly processing a pbf file will be very inefficient because it just contains raw data. This file format is not optimized for running queries on it. You need to pre-process this file, calculate a routing graph, drop uninteresting data and then store it in some kind of database or a similar efficient format.

For really long distances consider using [contraction hierarchies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies). They are used by many popular OSM routers, such as [graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/) and [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/).

It also helps to take a look at the various different [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) for OSM in order to get some ideas.

Comment: osmsharp also utilizes contraction hierarchies if I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes, I believe OsmSharp does preprocessing when it loads the PBF.